# Formal way to say "if it doesn't work out for you, then never mind"

Tags: formality

I am writing an email asking for a change of meeting time. The recipient is a very important client who I've never met. And here is what I wrote:

> Please ignore the request if it causes inconvenience for you, and I will meet you at the originally scheduled time.

I would like to know if this is formal enough, and whether if it expresses my idea clearly. Thank you!

Comment: There's no standard for formality.

Comment: I think your sentence is just right.  Yes, it expresses your idea clearly and is polite and to the point.  It is certainly not informal, and being more formal would involve a lot of meaningless words.

Comment: If he follows your instructions to the letter, how will you know whether he’s planning on meeting you at the new or original time?

Comment: If the client is that important, It is not a very good idea to try to change the schedule. Why not change your own schedule? It might prompt your client to have a second thought about doing business with you. I would if I were him or her especially when it creates any convenience for me when I am extremely busy.

Comment: Not enough context. To be polite, any request for an optional change should be couched in tentative language to begin with, not supplemented with a "Please ignore the request" statement.

Comment: @Jim By negative communication - if you don't hear back by the scheduled time, conclude that the request was ignored, as requested. It's an unreliable protocol to use and susceptible to failures at any point in the chain of transmission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's confusing:  does "and I will meet you at the originally scheduled time" refer to the case where the reader ignores the email or the case where the reader **doesn't** ignore the email?  This confusion arises because of the use of "and": it's like you're saying the second part of the sentence will happen whatever the result of the first part is.

You could rewrite it thus:

*"If this request is not convenient then I can meet you at the originally scheduled time."*

EDIT: Changed "inconvenient" to "not convenient" as this is more formal and better suited to a business context: "inconvenient" sounds too personal.